# how tough is integration of React with iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs

I've gone through one nicely written tutorial using React Native on raywenderlich.com, but had a couple concerns around if React Native is ready for less trivial apps as well how well it integrates with swift/obj c

I was thinking of using it for one view, a view that would also have a webpage that presents the same data. But then would it be a pain to get that react native page to match the rest of the components written out in swift/storyboards? Does it make more sense to do the whole UI in react or not react? I am very new to react so I was wondering how much of the code would be reusable between native and web.

My app is a btle app where there is a lot of messaging. So stuff from bluetooth might have to talk to business logic object or a react component. Is the messaging from swift to javascript a bad performance hit or is it pretty reasonable?

The other thought I had was to use react for my networking, the idea being when going to Android, I would have less to port. Does that sound like it makes sense?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You're really only going to get opinion answers to this as the question is extremely broad.  You need to try out the technology (honestly, mocking up a few bits of what you describe would just take you a few minutes).

Comment: Thanks Mike. I always feel there are many gotchas that you only realize after a deeper dive into a technology. I was hoping someone might share insights or experiences which would be more than I would be able to get after a bit of mocking.